# getting ip details in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

Am trying to get all the IPv4 address from ipconfig set on the server.

Thanks to Chris for sharing info/solutions on number of ways to get the ip details.

worked solution :

```
Get-WmiObject @params | Select-Object NetConnectionID, `
        @{Name='IPAddress'; Expression={
            $_.GetRelated('Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration') | ForEach-Object {
                [IPAddress[]]$_.IPAddress | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' }
            }
        }}
```

Comment: There are so many ways to get interface information that don't involve parsing ipconfig. Why not use Get-NetIPConfiguration (if you have that) or WMI if you do not?

Comment: And considering what you're doing here, you should check out https://github.com/PowerShell/Operation-Validation-Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments above, these examples use WMI to extract the interface name and IPv4 addresses.

There are different ways to derive this depending on what's most important. That is, pick the version with the most convenient filtering style.

**Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration and IPEnabled = TRUE**

Useful if you are interested in all IP-enabled interfaces.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE'" |
    Select-Object @{n='NetConnectionID';e={ ($_ | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter).NetConnectionID }},
                  @{n='IPAddress';e={ [IPAddress[]]$_.IPAddress | Where-Object AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' }}
```

**Win32_NetworkAdapter and a named interface**

Perhaps best if you need to target an interface by name and get the IP.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='Ethernet'" |
    Select-Object NetConnectionID,
                @{n='IPAddress';e={
                    [IPAddress[]]($_ | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).IPAddress |
                        Where-Object AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'
                }}
```

**Get-WmiObject**

Get-WmiObject has been superseded, but if you prefer the syntax of that, here's the first example again.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE'" |
    Select-Object @{n='NetConnectionID';e={ $_.GetRelated("Win32_NetworkAdapter") | ForEach-Object { $_.NetConnectionID } }},
                  @{n='IPAddress';e={ [IPAddress[]]$_.IPAddress | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } }}
```

**Using System.Net.NetworkInformation**

Because WMI isn't the only way, this also provides direct access with very little work.

```
$Name = 'MGT'
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() |
    Where-Object Name -eq $Name |
    Select-Object Name,
            @{n='IPAddress';e={ $_.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Address |
                Where-Object AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork'
            }}
```

**Get-NetworkInterface function (PowerShell 2 compatible)**

This function allows you to pick network interfaces by name so you can check the IP addresses. By default it returns information for all named interfaces.

```
function Get-NetworkInterface {
    param(
        [String]$Name = '*',

        [String]$ComputerName
    )

    $params = @{
        Class = 'Win32_NetworkAdapter'
    }
    if ($Name.IndexOf('*') -gt -1) {
        $Name = $Name -replace '\*', '%'
        $params.Add('Filter', "NetConnectionID LIKE '$Name'")
    } else {
        $params.Add('Filter', "NetConnectionID='$Name'")
    }
    if ($ComputerName -ne '') {
        $params.Add('ComputerName', $ComputerName)
    }

    Get-WmiObject @params | Select-Object NetConnectionID, `
        @{Name='IPAddress'; Expression={
            $_.GetRelated('Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration') | ForEach-Object {
                [IPAddress[]]$_.IPAddress | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' }
            }
        }}
}
```

**Operational validation**

This part is not PowerShell 2 compatible. This is how you might leverage a unit testing framework, [pester](https://github.com/pester/pester) in this case, to perform configuration validation.

It shows how I imagine you might use the function above to validate IP configuration.

```
Import-Module Pester
Describe 'SomeServer' {
    $ComputerName = 'SomeServer'

    Context 'Network configuration' {
        It 'Should have the management interface set to 10.1.2.3' {
            (Get-NetworkInterface -Name 'MGMT' -ComputerName 'SomeServer').IPAddress | Should Be '10.1.2.3'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you the Information. It will be very helpful. now, I did run all your given solutions but I guess am missing some info.                        for the first solution I get error saying "The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" commandnotfound Exception. Am using Powershell V2 not sure if this is supported in V2.   for  2nd and 3rd solution, I get blank results only header info.

Comment: for 4th solution, I get error saying "Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Name" value of type "System.String" to type "S
ystem.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: Ohh PowerShell 2... it's been so long. I only quickly tested under PowerShell 5. You'll need the Get-WmiObject version. Actually, that needs a compatibility tweak, one moment.

Comment: I've edited the Get-WmiObject version to be PowerShell 2 compatible, please let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Thanks Chris. updated Get-WmiObject version works now. Is there a way I can store the "NetConnectionID" values to a array and same for "IPAddress" so, in my script, I don't have to hardcode the $Adapters ("NetConnectionID") instead first get the Adapters what been set and then verify the IP's. I was thinking to my script more GENERIC so, can be used to other servers where we might won't have same $Adapters..

Comment: Edited the post above. Since you have adapters in an array I envisaged you would loop through that array, request specific interfaces by name, then inspect the values you need to directly (based on that single instance).

Comment: $Adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE'" | Select-Object @{n='NetConnectionID';e={ $_.GetRelated("Win32_NetworkAdapter") | ForEach-Object { $_.NetConnectionID } }} | select -expand NetConnectionID                      This $Adapters gives me all the adapter names. now I tried same for getting IP's but no luck (as I don't know how or which objectname to call for)... If I get all IP's to variable then again use same foreach loop for verification.

Comment: $Adapters.NetConnectionID is an array of NetConnectionID. $Adapters.IPAddress is an array of IPAddress.

Comment: PowerShell 2... it makes everything harder. You might have to go for `$Adapters | ForEach-Object  { $_.IPAddress }`

Comment: Sorry, please ignore. I got the ipaddress too. just  that I needed to do extra filter with $Adapters | select -expand IPAddressToString

Comment: Do we have -join? I can't remember you know :) Otherwise if you've assigned the result of your select above it should concatenate that when in a string ("$myvar") based on the value $ofs (Output Field Separator, space by default).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Concatenation worked just using ("$a$b$c"). I have updated my original post incase if anyone find in same situation.